# How can I solve 1. $yy'+x=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x^2+y^2}{x})^2$ and 2. $y'=(\frac{3x+y^3-1}{y})^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

At school we were given the following differential equation to solve:

a) $yy'+x=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x^2+y^2}{x})^2$ and

b) $y'=(\frac{3x+y^3-1}{y})^2$.

What I know now are:

1. DE with separable variables
2. Homogeneous DE of the 1st order
3. Linear DE
4. Bernoulli DE
5. Riccati's DE
6. Lagrange's DE
7. Clairotova DE

Experiment: I transformed the first equation (a) example) into

$y'y^2=9x^2+y^6+1+6xy^3-6x-2y^3$

by squaring, and the second into

$x^2y'+x^3 /y=1/(2y)x^4+x^2y+(1/2)y^3$.

How do I proceed as I can't see which type I could even use with which?

Comment: Is $y' = dy/dx$ or $y' = dy/dt$?

Comment: Here is y'=dy/dx.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought these were a coupled system. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: no, it is about two completely independent differential equations - we look at each separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

For the first,

$$
\frac 12(y(x)^2)'+x = \frac 12\left(\frac{x^2+y(x)^2}{x}\right)^2
$$

making $z = y^2$ we have

$$
\frac 12 z' + x = \frac 12\left(\frac{x^2+z}{x}\right)^2
$$

and also

$$
z'+2x = (x^2+z)'
$$

so we can follow with $u = x^2+z$ and

$$
\frac 12 u' = \frac 12\left(\frac{u}{x}\right)^2
$$

which is separable, etc.

and for the second

$$
y^2y'=\left(3x+y^3-1\right)^2
$$

calling $z = y^3$ we have

$$
\frac 13 z' = \left(3x+z-1\right)^2
$$

etc.

Comment: So what type is the second equation?

Comment: That is left to you. As you said in your question, you are capable to solve it.

Comment: It looks like Riccati's DE, but what will be one solution?

Comment: You can continue making $u = z+3x-1$

Comment: Oh yes, i get 1/3(u'-3)=u^2. Right?

Comment: Is it separable?

Comment: Yes, it is separable.